# How to add/remove children from DocumentFragment after it has inserted into parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use `DocumentFragment` as an insertion point of other elements something like this:

```js
const parent = document.createElement('div');
const container = document.createDocumentFragment();
parent.appendChild(container);

// the following code should produce <div><p></p></div>
const child = document.createElement('p');
container.appendChild(child);

// when the following code execute it should produce <div></div>
container.removeChild(child);
```

The main problem is it does not work. Any elements inserted into `container` after it was inserted into `parent` does not get rendered in `parent`. My goal is I want `container` to act like a transparent parent to its children so CSS selector will see its children as a children of `parent`.

Comment: "My goal is I want container to act like a transparent parent to its children so CSS selector will see its children as a children of parent." I don't understand what you mean by this. If you want the `child` to be a direct descendant of `parent` then why use the `container` at all?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how appendChild works with documentFragment. Using appendChild of a document fragment appends the fragments children, not the fragment itself.

See [Dom Standard - 4.2.3. Mutation algorithms - "To insert a node into a parent...](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-insert)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot accomplish this using `DocumentFragment`. See [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment#usage_notes):

> A common use for `DocumentFragment` is to create one, assemble a DOM
> subtree within it, then append or insert the fragment into the DOM […]
> Doing this moves the fragment's nodes into the DOM, **leaving behind an
> empty DocumentFragment**.

You can check this behaviour using the console:

```
> const container = document.createDocumentFragment();
> container.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
> container // contains the span element
▼ #document-fragment
    <span>​</span>​
> const parent = document.createElement('div');
> parent.appendChild(container);
> parent
▼ <div>
    ​<span>​</span>
  ​</div>​
> container // is now empty
    #document-fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Build entire document fragment.
Then appendChild()

Then look up root of fragment appended (it's now inserted)
and add and remove children as you like.